# Event listeners and refs in React 16

Tags: reactjs

I have an element whose width I want to set equal to the parent both when the element is rendered and when the parent is resized. I'm using the new `React.createRef` API to achieve this and currently have the following:

```
class Footer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.footerRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = { width: 0 };
  }

  updateWidth() {
    const width = this.footerRef.current.parentNode.clientWidth;
    this.setState({ width });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWidth();
    this.footerRef.current.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.footerRef.current.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
  }

  render() {
    const { light, setEqualToParentWidth, className, ...props } = this.props;

    const style = setEqualToParentWidth
      ? { ...props.style, width: this.state.width }
      : { ...props.style };

    return (
      <footer
        {...props}
        ref={this.footerRef}
        style={style}
        data-ut="footer"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This seems to compile without any errors and accurately sizes itself on mount. However, once it has mounted, changing the viewport width does not change the width of the footer. Am I attaching the event listener incorrectly?

I also initially tried attaching the event listener to `window`, but that resulted in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined` on the first line of `updateWidth` when I attempted to resize my screen.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the window `resize` event. When you assign the event listener you need to bind to the proper scope inside your constructor `this.updateWidth = this.updateWidth.bind(this);`

This should also be debounced.

Try this:

```
class FooterBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.footerRef = React.createRef();
    this.updateWidth = this.updateWidth.bind(this);
    this.state = { width: 0 };
  }

  updateWidth() {
    const width = this.footerRef.current.parentNode.clientWidth;
    this.setState({ width });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWidth();

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWidth);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWidth);
  }

  render() {
    const { light, setEqualToParentWidth, className, ...props } = this.props;

    const style = setEqualToParentWidth
      ? { ...props.style, width: this.state.width }
      : { ...props.style };

    return (
      <footer
        {...props}
        ref={this.footerRef}
        style={style}
        data-ut="footer"
      ></footer>
    );
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/kieran/pen/ZMrrgw?editors=1010)

Comment: Ah silly me, I forgot to bind it. I guess I need to do that since it's being called outside of the class, right? Also, what do you mean by `This should also be debounced.`?

Comment: debounce the resize event so you can limit the number of renders that happen

Comment: quick explanation - https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Thanks, will look into incorporating that in there too!

Comment: A bit too late on this issue. If i declare the updateWidth function as an arrow function, does it get bind to this automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately, it will not. You'll need to use the class properties transform plugin https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties to handle binding if you aren't going to handle the binds inside the constructor.