# Enzyme testing event listeners in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

This is a follow up on a previous question I asked, [Event listeners and refs in React 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266222/event-listeners-and-refs-in-react-16). I'm trying to implement a test to make sure that the resize event is properly being listened to and handled with the `updateWidth` function in my component. I have the following test:

```
  it(`should always listen to 'resize' event and handle it with 'updateWidth'`, () => {
    const map = {};
    window.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, callback) => {
      map[event] = callback;
    });

    const wrapper = mount(<Footer {...props} />);

    // simulate event
    map.resize();

    expect(wrapper.updateWidth).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received: undefined
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `props` object is, but if it includes the `updateWidth` method, then you need `expect(wrapper.props().updateWidth).toHaveBeenCalled();` or simply `expect(props.updateWidth).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: `updateWidth` is an internal method, not being passed with props. For reference, props is `{ className: 'somestring', setEqualToParentWidth: undefined }`

Comment: try `const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper, 'updateWidth')` and then `map.resize()` and then `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Comment: When I try that, I get the error: `Cannot spy the updateWidth property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Comment: how about `const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'updateWidth')`

Comment: Now the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateWidth' of null`